# duplicate spinbox decliration in QT causing build issue

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

im sure you get this a lot, but im still learning the ropes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIpOa.png)

Here is an error I get because I created a second slot for a spinboxValue changed.
I can comment it out and run the program with no issue but the issue keeps returning.

what is the correct way to remove this slot.
For reference, i right clicked and selected the go to slot for a second time, thinking that it will take me to the slot that was already created.

The error is in a file that i did not create and can only access it by forcing the error to reoccurred (to my knowledge)

Comment: I think you have to show your minimal code that produces this moc output. I have never had this happen to me in the 13 years I have used Qt between home and work. I don't use Qt 6 however.

Comment: The moc files are created from your class definitions so remove the slot there.